# stabilizer of gauge group

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory

Suppose $A$ is a flat connection on a fiber bundle $V$ over a manifold $M$, with fiber $G$. What is the stabilizer of the action of the gauge group on the space of all flat connections (i.e. $g(x)\cdot A=A$)? Can we conclude that $g(x)$ is a constant map?

Comment: That sounds confusing. If you're on the moduli space of flat connections, you've taken the quotient of the space of flat connections, by the gauge group.  So by definition, the entire gauge group acts trivially. Do you mean the space of flat connections?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I edited the problem. Yes, I meant all flat connections.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given in lemma 6.1.4 of Rudolph & Schmidt's, "Differential Geometry and Mathematical Physics: Part II", and the theorem that follows. See there for details. It states the following:

Let $v_0\in V$, and let $A$ be a connection on $V$ and $g\in\mathcal{G}$ a gauge transformation. Then $g\cdot A=A$ if and only if the restriction of $g$ to the holonomy bundle $P_{p_0}(A)$ is constant.

They go on to prove the following:

The isotropy group $\mathcal{G}_A$ is isomorphic to the centraliser of the holonomy group in $G$.

Note that, for a flat connection, the holonomy group is necessarily discrete, by the Ambrose-Singer theorem. However, its centraliser is not necessarily all of $G$.